# Searching in dataframe and updating if found in column

Tags: r

In R, I have a dataframe on which I have run data mining and excluded irrelavent words. Then I created two word and three word combinations; now I want to search these combinations in my main dataframe and add column with the matching two word or three word combination so that I can get accurate number instead of frequency of occurrence

Here is the sample:

```
##ID    Title 
###123  Product - power supply has failed 
###124  Product - hard drive has been degraded 
###125  Product - hard drive failed 
###126  Product - hard drive is failed 
###127  Product - hdd failed 
###128  Product - power supply is down 
###129  Product - hard drive is not working 
###130  Product - hard drive not functioning 
###131  Product - hard drive is not working 
###132  Product - Power supply is not working 

Output should be:
## ID Title [Keywords Matched]
example
##ID    Title                               [Keywords Matched]
###123  Product - power supply has failed   `power supply`
```

I have come-up with a function which loops through a set of keywords and searching them one at a time in dataframe and marks if found - however, it gives error when I try adding new column; but it works fine if I do it outside the function; can you pls check where is the issue:

```
# Function to write keywords
AssignKeywords <- function(x){

  keyword <<- as.character(freq2.df$word[x])

  #print (which(grepl('hard drive',tolower(Working.Data$Case.Title))))
  MatchingList <-  which(grepl(keyword,tolower(Data.New$Issue)))

  for(i in MatchingList)
  {

    if(is.na(Data.New$keywords[i]))
    {
      print('keyword is not null')
      print(Data.New$keywords[i])

      Data.New$keywords[i] <<- as.character(na.omit(keyword))
    }
  }
  #print (x)
  #print (MatchingList)
  #print ('completed')
}

# Function to Add column for keywords and loop through keywords and update matching ones in data frame
AddKeywords <- function(){

  # Add keywords Column and set to NA
  Data.New$keywords <- NULL
  if("keywords" %in% colnames(Data.New))
  {
    print('keyword column exists')
  } else
  {
    print('Keywords column does not exist')
    Data.New$keywords <- NA

    print('keyword column does not exists')

  }

  # Run counter and loop through all the keywords and add to main data frame
  counter <- 0
  while(counter != (length(freq2.df$word)))
  {
    counter <- counter + 1

    AssignKeywords(counter)

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include a sample of your data, code you have tried, and what you would expect the results to look like?

Comment: Here is the sample data: 
ID Title
123 Product - power supply has failed
234 Product - hard drive has been degraded
235 Product - hard drive failed
345 Product - hard drive is failed
367 Product - hdd failed
398 Product - power supply is down
333 Product - hard drive is not working
364 Product - hard drive not functioning
390 Product - hard drive is not working
391 Product - Power supply is not working

here the words "is not has been" etc would be removed and using the termdocumentmatrix would generate a two letter and three letter combination and check the frequency.

Comment: Issue with frequency is there might be two words in one sentence so count will be two. So I want to check each two word combination and three word combination in the dataframe and add two columns where in one matches the two word combination and other matches three word combination. I am not sure how to extract each of the two/three word combination words and search in dataframe and mark in the new columns.

Comment: @Sam I have updated the post, please check and let me know how to get the results

Comment: I still am not certain of the results you're trying to obtain. Also, please edit your original question, such that I can be sure what your original data looks like (use code blocks). It seems like this should be possible, but until I see what you would like to see as the results of this sample data, I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's an example I drew up that takes care of the data that you have in the sample. It would probably need to be extended out to handle the actual data you're dealing with, since I'm not sure of the complexity of your data, or the keywords you're trying to match (can a Title have multiple keyword matches? etc.) Either way, I used `grepl` to match keywords, and `str_replace_all` to change hdd to hard drive. I imagine you put that in there since you could very easily have multiple aliases that you all want to mean a single word. Let me know if this does or doesn't work for you.

```
### Loads data frame

df <- data.frame(ID = c('###123', '###124', '###125', '###126', '###127', '###128', 
                        '###129', '###130', '###131', '###132'),
                 Title = c('Product - power supply has failed',
                           'Product - hard drive has been degraded',
                           'Product - hard drive failed',
                           'Product - hard drive is failed',
                           'Product - hdd failed',
                           'Product - power supply is down',
                           'Product - hard drive is not working',
                           'Product - hard drive not functioning',
                           'Product - hard drive is not working',
                           'Product - Power supply is not working'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

### Change hdd to hard drive

library('stringr')
df$Title <- str_replace_all(df$Title, 'hdd', 'hard drive')

### Create keywords column

df$keywordsMatched <- ''
df$keywordsMatched <- ifelse(grepl('power supply', df$Title, ignore.case = TRUE), 
                             'power supply', df$keywordsMatched)
df$keywordsMatched <- ifelse(grepl('hard drive', df$Title, ignore.case = TRUE), 
                             'hard drive', df$keywordsMatched)

df

       ID                                  Title keywordsMatched
1  ###123      Product - power supply has failed    power supply
2  ###124 Product - hard drive has been degraded      hard drive
3  ###125            Product - hard drive failed      hard drive
4  ###126         Product - hard drive is failed      hard drive
5  ###127            Product - hard drive failed      hard drive
6  ###128         Product - power supply is down    power supply
7  ###129    Product - hard drive is not working      hard drive
8  ###130   Product - hard drive not functioning      hard drive
9  ###131    Product - hard drive is not working      hard drive
10 ###132  Product - Power supply is not working    power supply
```

Comment: Thank you Sam.. This gave me an idea on how to search. The keywords that I am looking at is output of a TermDocumentMatrix with 2 letter combination and 3 letter combination - I needed a way to loop through these words and then match them the way you did

Comment: I have updated the question with the function; can you pls check the issue